# How to get terminal to run 24bit true color in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I'm wanting to run 24bit true color within the terminal. How may I do this?

I've ran the command `apt-cache show gnome-shell | grep Version` and it throws out `3.18.4-0ubuntu3`

Comment: You don't.  Terminals only support 16 colors.

Comment: @psusi That's so much not true. Nowadays pretty much all terminal emulators support 256 colors, and many of them support 16 million (aka 24bit true colors) as well.

Comment: @egmont, interesting... I didn't know there was an ANSI escape sequence to specify more than 4 bits of background and 4 bits of foreground color.

Answer (score 3):

GNOME Terminal supports true color in 16.04.

Source: https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728

Trying out the test code from that gist:

[image: gnome-terminal with the zsh shell showcasing its support for 24 bit colors; courtesy of Ask Ubuntu user grooveplex]

Comment: @grooveplex I'm mildly curious as to what's "more generic" in this. My screenshot also uses GNOME Terminal and zsh. I just set the prompt to a barebones `$`.